# After disconnecting my external hard disk (WD Elements) from High Sierra and connecting it to Ventura it didn't work

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk

I used my external disk on my Sierra device. When I was done, I disconnected it from the Eject feature and set it aside. A few weeks later I installed it on my Ventura. It can see my external disk but cannot connect to it. I repaired the disk but it shows that the EFI partition is damaged. How can I access my data?

EDIT: I tried mounting it. Failed. I've been trying through the terminal, but I haven't gotten any results.

[I tried to solve this problem by contacting WD support department, but instead of helping, they wanted to replace the disk.]

[image: Disk Utility]

[image: EFI]

Comment: Does it still work on the "High Sierra" Mac? That would tell you if the problem is with the drive or the "Ventura" Mac.

Comment: Thank you, Steve for replay. No. I see it in the Disk Utility software in Sierra, but I cannot access my files. Everything is as it seems in Ventura.

Comment: Well, if it is fine on Mac "A" and not fine on Mac "B" then the problem is likely with Mac "B". In *rare occasions* I have seen peripherals, cables and whatnot work on one computer just fine and not on another. There is a slim chance that the issue is with the cable, the case that the drive is in or the drive itself. I would be tempted to replace it. Computers are complex beasts and sometimes an error not noticed by one computer fails completely on another. If the replacement drive *still* exhibits the same symptoms, then you need to look at Mac "B" as the problem and not the drive.